# Using common Jekyll code for multiple github pages websites

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm wanting to have both a user website and multiple project websites hosted on Github Pages i.e.

- username.github.io
- username.github.io/project1
- username.github.io/project2

I'd like them to share a common set of jekyll files so it's easier to change themes, info, etc.. Has anyone managed to do this? Using subtree / submodule isn't too helpful because you cannot overwrite the **source** config option to change the location of the jekyll source files. Github Pages always forces the **source** to be in the root directory. You can change where **_includes** and **_layouts** reside but that's not too useful. Any advice or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `username.github.ui/base` as your repository with your base templates. This shouldn't be a gh-page.

This repository should contain a branch with your base templates. For the moment, I say you are using the `master` branch for that. Branch out and create a `project1` and `project2` branch in this repo.

Every time you change your base templates, change them in the `master` branch and then merge the master branch into `project1` and `project2`.

Clone the `base` repo locally, and add `project1` and `project2` both as remotes.

Then simply do a `git push project1 project1:gh-pages` to push your local `project1` branch to the first projects gh-pages branch.

This will still multiply the files, but it will mean that you can easily keep them in sync. Changing your base templates would be like this:

1. `git pull` project1's gh-pages branch into the base repos `project1` branch. Repeat for project2.
2. Change the base templates in the appropriate branch in the `base` repo.
3. Merge the branch into the `project1` and `project2` branches
4. `git push` project1's branch into project1`s`gh-pages` branch. Repeat for #2.

If you set up some hooks this can be automated fairly easy.